# SQL/ PHP Joining table, ignoring multiple records

Tags: php, sql, join

I don't really know how to even search for resolution of this problem, didn't find anything specific, so here goes...

I have four tables, let's simplify them:

```
  players
  =======
  id    name    surname
  1     John    Arbuckle
  2     Walter  White
  3     Don Draper
  4     Louis   CK
  5     Tyrion  Lannister
  6     Abed    Nadir

  sports
  ======
  id    sport
  1     football
  2     handball

  positions
  =========
  id    name    sport_id
  1     goalie  1
  2     defense 1
  3     attack  1
  4     goalie  2
  5     pivot   2
  6     wing    2
  7     center  2

  player_position
  ===============
  player_id position_id
  1         1
  1         2
  1         5
  2         7
  2         5
  3         2
  4         2
  5         1
  5         3
  6         7
  6         5
```

So, player can play multiple sports and on multiple positions. First, I have to display list of players for a certain sport, including a column with positions they play.

What I started with is JOIN statement where I'd join those tables and have multiple rows for each player ID. That's close, but not very correct. And what I need to get is a tables like this:

FOOTBALL

```
    ID  name    surname     position
    1   John    Arbuckle    PHP array(goalie,defense)
```

HANDBALL

```
    ID  name    surname     position
    1   John    Arbuckle    PHP array(pivot)
```

EDIT:
So what I was looking for was GROUP_CONCAT().
Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you looked into GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: @MihaiStancu That's what I was looking for! Thanks! (yes, DB was MySQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.id, p.name, p.surname, group_concat(po.name)
from players p 
inner join player_position pp on pp.player_id = p.id
inner join positions po on po.id = pp.position_id
inner join sports s on s.id = po.sport_id
where s.sport = 'football'
group by p.id
```

See this [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2250d/12)

Comment: Thanks! GROUP_CONCAT was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is foolproof (not tested) but…

```
SELECT pp.`player_id` AS 'ID',s.`id` AS 'sport_id',s.`sport`,ps.`name` AS 'position',pl.`name`,pl.`surname` FROM `sports` s
INNER JOIN `positions` ps ON s.`id`=ps.`sport_id`
INNER JOIN `player_position` pp ON pp.`position_id`=ps.`id`
INNER JOIN `players` pl ON pl.`id`=pp.`player_id`
ORDER BY s.`id`,pp.`player_id`,ps.`id`
```

Here's a more detailed version:

```
SELECT
    s.`id` AS 'sport_id',s.`sport`,
    ps.`id` AS 'position_id',ps.`name` AS 'position',
    pl.`id` AS 'player_id',pl.`name`,pl.`surname`
FROM `sports` s
INNER JOIN `positions` ps ON s.`id`=ps.`sport_id`
INNER JOIN `player_position` pp ON pp.`position_id`=ps.`id`
INNER JOIN `players` pl ON pl.`id`=pp.`player_id`
ORDER BY s.`id`,pp.`player_id`,ps.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

**For football:**

```
SELECT players.name, players.surname, positions.name 
FROM players, sports, positions, player_position 
WHERE sports.id = 1 AND positions.sport_id = sports.id AND payer_position.position_id = positions.id AND players.id = player_position.player_id;
```

**For Handball:**

```
SELECT players.name, players.surname, positions.name 
FROM players, sports, positions, player_position 
WHERE sports.id = 2 AND positions.sport_id = sports.id AND payer_position.position_id = positions.id AND players.id = player_position.player_id;
```